# ad vs ldap authentication on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap

I have been using AD authentication on Jenkins for a while but now there is a requirement to restrict access to Jenkins to a particular group and to do this we would now need to use ldap directly for user authentication.
However, i have been unable to set it up correctly. I have tried browsing the ldap using different gui and cli tools and so far all of them are unable to find my domain DN 'abc.xyz'. Is it possible that ldap might not be setup correctly for my domain?

There are like 5 DN's that I could find out using ldap browser. Using an AD browser I was also able to find 5 DNs but the DN I use with AD is not listed in the LDAP list of DNs. All the other four DNs are the same except the one which i use for AD authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it sound like you're trying to find the DN of your domain?

You can determine the DN (distinguished name) of a domain from the domain name. If your domain is "abc.xyz" then the DN would be:

```
DC=abc,DC=xyz
```

If you want it to only look at one OU, then you can use this:

```
OU=myOu,DC=abc,DC=xyz
```

I have no experience with Jenkins, but I know AD/LDAP fairly well. Are you using their [AD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin) or the [LDAP plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin)?

Comment: i was using their AD plugin previously but decided to move to LDAP for restricting access based on groups and roles. However you were correct, the ldap domain was not correct. Our network is very weirdly set-up. All PCs are on 'abc.xyz' domain but all users are on 'efg.xyz' domain, xyz being the common part. Since i had no idea abotu LDAP, i used a few tools to set to find the ldap id(the default uri didn't work) adn they all showed the 'abc.xyz' domain but what i needed was 'efg.xyz' domain. I hope that made a little bit of sense.

Comment: weirdly set up for me to make sense*

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. At my work we have a similar setup: all computers are on one domain, users are on one of several domains we have. So if your users are on "efg.xyz", you'd use "LDAP://efg.xyz" as the server, and "DC=efg,DC=xyz" as the base DN.

Comment: Sorry if this confuses things, but looking at the [documentation for their AD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin), you can override the domain controller so it points at a different domain than the one the computer is joined to. You'd set the "Domain controller" field to "efg.xyz:389". If your users can be on more than one domain, but all in the same AD forest, than you can use "efg.xyz:3268".